# Changing Title for several IDs with Javascript, calculating from original value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Code take the title of a TD tag in order to get the difference of time between
two time in a string
(ie. 13:01-14:03) and show it like a new title(property), this apply only for a only element, when I have more than one, it fails.
How can I do it work for this case??

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
        <th>Ok</th>

    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>CCBB</td>
        <td class='huifa' id='calc' title='02-01-2013 13:01-14:03'>231</td>
        <td class='huifa' id='calc' title='02-01-2013 13:01-13:53'>1</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>CCBB</td>
        <td>342</td>
        <td>0</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

JS CODE

```
<script>
element = document.getElementById('calc');
v = element.title
v = v.slice(11)
v = v.split('-')
totalTime = delTime(v[1],v[0]);
element.title = 'Duracion: '+totalTime
</script>
```

My working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cespinoza/tg86a/55/

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with an ID, use a class

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: the problem is, you have multiple elements with the same ID. ID's are meant to be unique, you can't have duplicate IDs. you should change those to classes, and find the classes.

Comment: It's worth adding that, while this is an HTML error (and produces invalid HTML), the problem is that `document.getElementById()` returns only *one* element (the *first*, since there ***shouldn't be any other elements with that `id`***). Still, the solution is the same: use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, change the `id='calc'` to `class='calc'`. then change your code to this:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  v = elements[i].title;
  v = v.slice(11);
  v = v.split('-');
   totalTime = delTime(v[1],v[0]);
   elements[i].title = 'Duration: ' + totalTime;                             
}
```